# foreach over Hashtable stops on first key

Tags: c#, foreach, hashtable, dispose, event-log

I have a Hashtable that contains numerous EventLog objects. In my FormClosed event, I need to iterate through those so I can dispose of those objects, but on the very first key, the focus goes back to the form and the method never finishes (and the form never closes). Why is it doing this/what's wrong with this approach?

```
private void Main_FormClosed(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // There will probably be lots of stuff that we'll need to dispose of when closing
        if (servers.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string key in servers)
            {
                try
                {
                    EventLog el = (EventLog)servers[key];
                    el.Dispose();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: You shouldn't swallow exceptions.  What if something is going wrong?  You won't even know about it.  At the very, very least, you should be logging/printing the exception.

Comment: You may be envoking an error which is not handled.

Comment: I'm not aware of the use case of this, but .net automatically does GC and disposes of unused stuff. I believe there is no need to this manually.

Comment: try with `foreach (var value in servers.Values)`

Comment: @Aviatrix .NET most certainly does *not* automatically Dispose of things.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi In that case `var` would just evaluate to `object` because he's using a `HashTable` instead of a `Dictionary`.  If he used a `Dictionary` the compiler would know the type of what is being iterated.

Comment: @Servy: not saying he doesn't have to use a Dictionary but I suggested a method he could use with the HashTable, I agree about using Dictionary if possible.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi My point is that if he's not using a `Dictionary` `var` will be essentially useless.  It will evaluate to `object` which won't be helpful.  What he needs to do is know what the correct type should be (here it's `DictionaryEntry`) and put it there; `var` won't know what that correct type is.  `HashTable` only implements `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerable<T>`, which is why.  If it implemented `IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry>` then `var` would actually be useful.

Comment: @Sevy: I suggested to use `Values` collection from HashTable, var will evaluate to object but he knows the type of the items and he's actually doing a cast inside the foreach. He'll need to do the same cast but avoiding `Keys` collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterator of `Hashtable` iterates key-value pairs. If you would like to iterate keys, change your code as follows:

```
foreach (string key in servers.Keys)
```

Use `Hashtable` only if you must do so for backward compatibility; in .NET 2.0 and later, use `Dictionary<K,T>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

```
 private void Main_FormClosed(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            // There will probably be lots of stuff that we'll need to dispose of when closing
            if (servers.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string key in servers.Keys)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        EventLog el = (EventLog)servers[key];
                        el.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) 
                    {
                        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message); 
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why rethrow the exception (and clear the stack trace) when you catch it and do nothing else.  At that point you may as well just remove the try/catch entirely.

Comment: just for stop treatment on the client, but he can log exception or execute mute exception if is the functional need

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: i'am sorry for my english, 1 if you want log exception in order to trace or if need is propagate exception to up level

Comment: First off, you're virtually always better off with `throw;` over `throw ex;`.  Second, I would suggest adding a comment or placeholder of some sort to denote that `//logging goes here` if it's important for it to be added.

Comment: Thank's for remark, i added     EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message); in order to log